# List all days of week in query

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to list all days of the next week of given date

Example:

If today is `2019-09-24` then the result should be:

```
DAY_OF_WEEK

2019-09-24
2019-09-25
2019-09-26
2019-09-27
2019-09-28
2019-09-29
2019-09-30
```

This is the query I came up with and I wonder if there is more elegant way to achieve the same results:

```
SELECT date('now') AS DAY_OF_WEEK
UNION
SELECT date('now', '+1 day') AS DAY_OF_WEEK
UNION
SELECT date('now', '+2 day') AS DAY_OF_WEEK
UNION
SELECT date('now', '+3 day') AS DAY_OF_WEEK
UNION
SELECT date('now', '+4 day') AS DAY_OF_WEEK
UNION
SELECT date('now', '+5 day') AS DAY_OF_WEEK
UNION
SELECT date('now', '+6 day') AS DAY_OF_WEEK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. 
If you want you can use a [`CTE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) which returns only the numbers from `0` to `6` and select from it the number of days to add to the current date:

```
WITH days as (
  SELECT 0 AS day UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6
)
SELECT date('now', '+' || day || ' day') AS DAY_OF_WEEK FROM days
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5mR2SmwFh5k2Y2rZPo1Dog/0).
Or with a `RECURSIVE CTE`:

```
WITH RECURSIVE days(day) AS (
  SELECT 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT day + 1 FROM days
  LIMIT 7
)
SELECT date('now', '+' || day || ' day') AS DAY_OF_WEEK FROM days;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jCKgbc3NFQsW4tAYxcTHQf/1).
Results:

```
| DAY_OF_WEEK |
| ----------- |
| 2019-09-24  |
| 2019-09-25  |
| 2019-09-26  |
| 2019-09-27  |
| 2019-09-28  |
| 2019-09-29  |
| 2019-09-30  |
```